# "Group" animated objects

Tags: animation, keyframes, parent, groups

I have some objects which are animated, some by keying values (mostly shape keys) and some keying location and scale. The end result is a flower growing:
[image: Flower]

I would like to easily be able to duplicate the flower and modify it as a whole without having to select every part, and perhaps use it in a particle system but currently most of the objects are separate (the end of the flower is all parented to an empty). I have tried to parent the whole object to something but the animation starts to do interesting things...
[image: Oh dear...]

Ideally I would like something like groups in Photoshop where the whole object can be duplicated and manipulated as a whole but you can still modify the components. If I have to somehow "bake" the animation first this is not much of a problem though.

Comment: Can't you join the parts, instead of parenting? They will be still isolated from the others but still selectable (start with 1 vertex and then L key)?